# LC3 program power function?

Tags: assembly, lc3

I want to implement a function that powers a number in assembly language with LC-3.

I can use 4 registers R0, R1, R2 and R3, and use a nested loop.

To be more exact, it will power R2 to R3 so that R2^R3.

Here is my code so far:

```
MyPOW   ADD     R3, R3, #0
BRz     ZeroP
        AND     R0, R0, #0
        ADD     R1, R3, #0

; Outer Loop
OLoop   AND     R3, R3, #0
; Inner Loop
ILoop   ADD     R0, R0, R2
        ADD     R2, R2, #-1
        BRp     ILoop
        ADD     R3, R3, R0
        ADD     R1, R1, #-1
        BRp     OLoop
        RET

ZeroP   AND     R3, R3, #0
        ADD     R3, R3, #1
        RET
```

So MyPow is the name of the function and it will firstly check if R3 is 0 and if it is zero it will jump to ZeroP that immediately returns 1.

Otherwise, it will loop and multiply R2 itself by R3 times. That's what I was aiming to do.

Inner loop is expected to do the self-multiplication job and the outer loops is counting R3 with decrement so it will repeat R3 times.

But it does not work properly, it just does normal multiplication such as if R2 = 2 and R3 = 3 then it returns 6.

I cannot figure out why, can anyone please help? Thanks.

Comment: Your inner loop is wrong, it destroys `R2`. Use the single stepping feature of your simulator to see what is happening.

Comment: @Jester Yeah I have tried that but still don't know what is going on... can you give me a hint? Thanks

Comment: That was the hint ... `ADD R2, R2, #-1` changes `R2` but you need the original value in `R2` to keep adding it. Also your register usage is confusing, what do you need `R3` for?